# Create TxtBox that gets values from specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a visual follow up for the companie I am working for.

I want to have a specific visualisation of some data. But because columns are not in line with this data I can not have it totally visual. "See picture Note1"

[image: Snippet of the report]

Now I was thinking to create a txt box that will be the correct size and to put it where I want it and so that all values can be shown.

Therefore I would need to copy values from U44:X48 in to txt.box. "See picture Note2"
I would like to keep the formatting if possible so that Index figures are either green or red.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    TextBox1.MultiLine = True

    'vbNewLine (same as vbCrLf?)  
    'TextBox1.Value = CStr(Range("U45").Value) & vbCrLf & CStr(Range("U46").Value) & vbCrLf & CStr(Range("U47").Value)
     (same as code below?)



    TextBox1.Value = Range("U45").Value & vbCrLf & Range("U46").Value & vbCrLf & Range("U47").Value


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Textboxes are not suitable for formatted text.

Why don't you just split column F into 2 or more columns make them smaller and eg let the cell value overlap the columns where you scratced out with black? If needed you could also merge the ItemName over column F to H (in the example below).

[image]

Comment: Hi Peh, I would love to do so but the table below is a Pivottable and, what I know with my knowledge, I can not make the ItemName stretch over several columns.

Comment: @AL Ah, well then this won't work, but TextBoxes don't work neither.